# UITableView different cell heights in different sections (no rows)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm having a `UITableViewController` with two sections. Section 0 always contains 1 row with height 22px. I'm setting this with `heightForRowAtIndexPath`... Section 1 contains 0-n rows with height 44px. I'm also setting the height of these with `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

The problem is that when I have no rows in section 1, all the "fill out cells" will have height 22px, like the cell in section 0, instead of 44px as I would like them to be.

Is it possible to set the height of these fill out cells to 44px (the cells that are empty and added automatically to fill out the table view) even if I only have the one row that is 22px?

Here is what I get (to the left) and what I want (to the right):
[image: This is not what I want] [image: This is what I want]

Comment: why do you want this effect? maybe you need a row with 44px and hide it or set userInteraction = NO.

Comment: The row at the top is a kind of statusbar. The rest of the rows are the content. I'd like to find a way of doing it without adding an empty cell with height 44px in section 1

Comment: Can your "status bar" be a header view for section 1 instead of being its own section?

Comment: @HuskerJeff that's actually a really good idea. Being a header it will also stay on top when scrolling, neat. The only downside is that it might be a bit harder to animate it when I want it to disappear in a nice way, but I can live with that. Thanks! Write it as an answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making your "status bar" its own section, you could make it a header view for section 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the UITableView attributes in the XIB - you can set a default row height so that if otherwise stated, all these "fill out" cells are defaulted to 44px height. You say that the 22px cell is there anyway so I think it should do as a solution to your problem.

Comment: I tried skipping `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and setting the row height of my two prototype cells in Storyboard, but the "fill out" cells still default to 22px if there are no cells in section 1

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, beside the prototype cells you can adjust the row height of the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem here. Two sections, the first shows 3 cells with a smaller height and always with the same content and they should scroll with the table so they can't be a header. The rows below with a larger cell height are changing so sometimes there are none.

I adjusted the cell height of the tableView as well as for the prototype cells and assign the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` value properly, but this doesn't help. Somehow the tableView seems to repeat the cells from first section into the second one if there are no cells in the later.

Only solution so far seems to be the creation of an empty cell in the second section. That's just more complicated if you are using animated cells.